# Different between two sentence

Tags: sentence-construction

What is different between this two sentences?

> Rich American **do** not hurt this trade war but only ordinary American.
>
> Rich American **are** not hurt this trade war but only ordinary American.

Comment: Did you write that sentence? Or did you copy it incorrectly? Both are agrammatical.

Answer (score 1):

> What is different between this two sentences?
>   1. Rich American do not hurt this trade war but only ordinary American.
>   2. Rich American are not hurt this trade war but only ordinary American.

Well, they are both wrong.

I have to assume that you mean:

> Rich Americans are not hurt **by** this trade war; only ordinary Americans.

Although without further context most people would want some clarification on what you mean by "rich" and "ordinary".

Answer (score 0):

First, use "Americans". It's plural, which you could have understood from the verb conjugation. Then:

> Rich Americans **do** not hurt this trade war, but only ordinary Americans *are hurt*.

implies a lack of injury to the "trade war". The action is toward the direct object.

> Rich Americans **are** not hurt *by* this trade war but only ordinary Americans *are hurt*.

implies the lack of injury to the "Rich Americans". *are* being intransitive refers the "not hurt" back to the subject (the Rich Americans).

The second clause (but only ordinary Americans) really needs a verb to be clear.